# Difference between deeper and wider neural networks

Tags: neural-networks

I'm learning NN and trying to understand the implication that architecture selection has in the model. Am I inferring correctly that:

- Wider neural networks can approximate more interactions between input variables
- Deeper neural networks can model more complex nonlinearities

Comment: Yes exactly like that, but as the net gets deeper, the effect like you mention might not be as prevalent.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222883/why-are-neural-networks-becoming-deeper-but-not-wider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly.

First, that's assuming all layers are created equal. Imagine you want to interleave two different activation functions for each layer, or add dropout - then deeper networks give you more legroom for those to work their magic.

Second, a very deep, moderately wide net may be able capture the same interactions as a shallow, absurdly wide one, but not vice versa.