# To design a Multilayer Perceptron, should I use more units per layer and less layers or more layers and less units, which is better?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I feel confused about how to design a Multilayer Perceptron(MLP). I have read a number of papers about how to design a deep CNN structure, like VGG or ResNet. However, for a Multilayer perceptron, a more basic ANN structure, should I follow this trend to make the MLP deeper? Actually, I try some trials on python that stacking more layers in one network, but the result showed it make no sense.

Therefore, I just wanna ask the question above.

can anybody give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The optimal neural network architecture depends on your data set.

FYI:

- [Why are neural networks becoming deeper, but not wider?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222883/12359)
- [What are the effects of depth and width in deep neural networks?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/214360/12359)
- [Is there any method for choosing the number of layers and neurons?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/232393/12359)

Comment: One more: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182734.